# Openwhisk build in local vagrant - apihost issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

Hi I standup a local openwhisk instance following https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk#alternate-instructions-for-mac-developers - which mostly worked.
I can now create user using wskadmin and see the tables created in cloudant instance - 
But after that when I try to invoke or list any action or package I get

```
ErrNo -2 - Service or Command not known

wsk package list or wsk action list
```

when I use verbose mode I see apihost is sent blank.
Any idea what's up with this and what should be apihost to begin with (I think it should be localhost but not working)

Answer (score 2):

The API host is your Vagrant machine IP address. From here: https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk#using-cli-from-outside-vagrant-machine

The virtual machine IP address is 192.168.33.13 (see Vagrant file). From your host, configure wsk to use your Vagrant-hosted OpenWhisk deployment and run the "echo" action again to test.

wsk property set --apihost 192.168.33.13 --auth

Comment: I am not trying from host
My intent is to run it from within the virtual machine.

Comment: @rahul then you need to port forward

Answer (score 1):

The same question and answer appear here: https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/issues/127